# Sequelize: how to count objects and update the rank?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How can I count objects and update it?

```
Post {
  id: Integer,
  rank: Integer
  ...
}
Vote: {
  id: Integer,
  post_id: Integer,
  up: Boolean
}
Post.hasMany(Vote, { foreignKey: 'post_id', sourceKey: 'id' })
Vote.belongsTo(Post, { foreignKey: 'post_id', sourceKey: 'id' })
```

I want to calculate the rank of all posts according to the score of `UpVote count` - `DownVote count`.

How can I do it with `Sequelize` ?

Answer (score -1):

You should not save any column which can be calculated in table.